# Recommended approach for route-based tests within routes of react-router

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, integration-testing, react-testing-library

I'm using react-testing-library within a project of mine and am trying to write tests that validate in-app routing.

e.g. testing that a button on the AccessDenied page brings you back to the Home page.

I've been able to write these sorts of tests successfully for my App component because it defines all of the app routes. But if AccessDenied *is one of those routes*, how do I need to set up my tests to validate a button clicked there will route my back to Home?

Here is a contrived example:

App.tsx

```
<>
  <Router>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route exact path="/access-denied" component={AccessDenied} />
  </Router>
  <Footer />
</>
```

AccessDenied.tsx

```
<div>
  <div>Access Denied</div>
  <p>You don't have permission to view the requested page</p>
  <Link to="/">
    <button>Go Home</button>    <--- this is what i want tested
  </Link>
</div>
```

As I said earlier the reason my tests work inside `App.test.tsx` is because my App component defines the routes inside itself, whereas my `AccessDenied` is just one of those routes. However, is it possible to leverage the router defined in my `App.tsx` in my `AccessDenied.test.tsx` tests? Perhaps I'm approaching this problem incorrectly? That's where I'm struggling. For reference, here is my working `App.test.tsx` tests.

App.test.tsx

```
describe('App', () => {
  it('should allow you to navigate to login', async () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory()
    const { findByTestId, getByTestId } = render(
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
        <AuthContext.Provider
          value={{
            authState: AUTH_STATES.UNAUTHENTICATED,
          }}
        >
          <Router history={history}>
            <App />
          </Router>
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      </MockedProvider>,
    )

    fireEvent.click(getByTestId('sidebar-login-button'))
    expect(await findByTestId('login-page-login-button')).toBeInTheDocument()

    fireEvent.click(getByTestId('login-page-register-button'))
    expect(await findByTestId('register-page-register-button')).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you think about the responsibility of the `AccessDenied` component, it isn't really to send the user *home*. That's the overall behaviour you want, but the component's role in that is simply to send the user to `"/"`. At the component unit level, therefore, the test could look something like this:

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import { Link, Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { createMemoryHistory } from "history";

const AccessDenied: FC = () => (
    <div>
        <div>Access Denied</div>
        <p>You don't have permission to view the requested page</p>
        <Link to="/">
            <button>Go Home</button>
        </Link>
    </div>
);

describe("AccessDenied", () => {
    it("sends the user back home", () => {
        const history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: ["/access-denied"] });
        render(
            <Router history={history}>
                <AccessDenied />
            </Router>
        );

        fireEvent.click(screen.getByText("Go Home"));

        expect(history.location.pathname).toBe("/");
    });
});
```

***Note** that `"/"` is the default path, so if you don't provide `initialEntries` the test passes even if the click doesn't do anything...*

At that point you might be thinking *"but what if the home route changes?"* If you moved the home page to `"/home"`, for example, this test would continue to pass but the application would no longer actually work. This is a common problem with relying too much on very low-level tests and is where *higher-level* tests come into play, including:

- **Integration**: render the whole `App` and use `fireEvent` to simulate navigation. This is challenging in your current setup, because the `Router` is at the `App` level; I'd move the `Router` to `index.tsx` and have a `Switch` in `App.tsx` instead, so you can render `App` within a `MemoryRouter` or use the `createMemoryHistory` method I show above (I've done this in [this starter kit](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/tree/master/client) for example).
- **End-to-end**: use a browser driver (e.g. Cypress or the various Selenium-based options) to automate actual user interactions with the app.

I haven't got as far as showing tests for routing, but do cover these different levels of test for a simple React app [on my blog](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Nov/22/js-tdd-e2e.html).

---

In React Router v6, you need to update the `Router` usage slightly (see ["Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')" when testing pages in the v6 React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69859509/3001761) for details):

```
render(
  <Router location={history.location} navigator={history}>
    <AccessDenied />
  </Router>
);
```

Comment: Thank you Jon for such a comprehensive answer! I like the idea of making the components unit tests simpler by just validating the location pathname. I'm not sure I follow why having the Router inside of the App component (in my real project it's actually in its own component nested inside of App) makes testing more difficult? Would you mind clarifying that?

Comment: @coloradocolby if the real Router is inside the app itself, you can't swap it out as easily as I do here when rendering the App. If you pull the Router up to the index file, you can render any component in a router context you control.

Comment: the update on router 6 was exactly what I finally needed to make it work! I wish it was better documented :/ Thanks @jonrsharpe !