# Suppress react error in console log during unit testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, error-handling

I'm experiencing an error when I am unit testing:

```
console.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
  Error: Uncaught [Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Redirect> outside a <Router>]
```

I know that this is due to the component I am testing having an un-wrapped `<Redirect>` element:

```
return <Redirect to={`${myRedirUrl}`}/>;
```

however this is being returned as part of a fully-fledged and wrapped `<ConnectedRouter>` so there is no issue with the app actually working. This complaint is merely during unit testing.

Is there anyway in which I can suppress this message during testing? The unit test is passing as I have been checking during trial runs, it's just annoying that the result is being buried...

---

**Component.jsx**

```
export const MyComp = () => {
  // /my-url will cause redirect to RedirectComponent
  return <Redirect to="/my-url" />
}
```

**Test**

```
it('should redirect without error', () => {
  const rendered = render(
      <Provider store={store(state)}>
          <BrowserRouter>
              <MyComponent />
              <Route path='/my-url'>Redirected</Route>
           </BrowserRouter>
       </Provider>
  );

  expect(rendered.container.textContent).toBe('Redirected');
});
```

This test passes as I have told it to expect the mock component, however I am getting the error as above due to the `MyComp` not having a wrapped `<Redirect>`

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually testing, but it's pretty easy to render the component in a `MemoryRouter` for a test, or do as I show in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65275037/3001761 and provide a history for testing purposes. See e.g. https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/testing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've updated my question with a bit more detail about the component/test. Looking at your solution, it didn't do anything to help suppress any errors.