# Testing useLocation() in React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-router

In my component that I want to test I use `useLocation` hook.
In the component I have:

```
function Test() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();
  const query = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('value');

  return <div > Welcome < /div>
}
```

To test the component I wrote this test:

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    useLocation: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        pathname: '',
        search: 'value',
        hash: '',
        state: null,
        key: '5nvxpbdafa',
    }),
}));

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    useHistory: () => jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        push: jest.fn(),
    }),
}));

describe(' page test', () => {
    test('should render', () => {
        render(<Test />);
        const title = screen.getByText(/welcome/i);

        expect(title).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
})
```

Trying this I get `TypeError: (0 , _reactRouterDom.useLocation) is not a function`. Why do I get this error? How to write the test correctly to avoid the error?

Comment: You're mocking it twice with two different implementations, only one of which has a `useLocation`. But you shouldn't be mocking it at all, you don't own that interface.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, i changed, but also i have in my code this: `const urlQuery = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('value');`, and  when i run this test i get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined`. Could you help please? How to solve this?

Comment: You could give a [mre] of that, but you'd be better off reading https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/testing. Again _don't mock what you don't own_, see also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65275037/3001761.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, i added some data in the question. Could you help?

Comment: Please re-read [mre]. Don't just post random snippets.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, my question was why i get the error if i set `search: 'value',`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, i added my component.

Comment: Still the old mock, though. And still the wrong approach. Also stop posting snippets that aren't actually runnable.

Answer (score 33):

You'd better don't mock `react-reouter-dom` and the implementation of `useLocation` hook. Instead, you should use [MemoryRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/MemoryRouter) wrap your component with [initialEntries](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/MemoryRouter/initialentries-array) for testing:

> An array of locations in the history stack. These may be full-blown location objects with { pathname, search, hash, state } or simple string URLs.

E.g.
`index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export function Test() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const query = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('value');
  console.log('query: ', query);

  return <div> Welcome </div>;
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Test } from './';

describe('68248240', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[{ pathname: '/', search: '?value=teresa_teng' }]}>
        <Test />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
  });
});
```

result:

```
 PASS  examples/68248240/index.test.tsx (10.807 s)
  68248240
    ✓ should pass (34 ms)

  console.log
    query:  teresa_teng

      at Test (examples/68248240/index.tsx:7:11)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.903 s
```

Comment: could you help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69124121/test-custom-hook-in-reactjs

Comment: what if I also need to wrap my component with `<BrowserRouter />`?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Provider store={mockStore}>
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[{ pathname: '/Admin/NotificationPreferences' }]}>
      <NotificationPreferences />
    </MemoryRouter>
  </Provider
```

> This is how I implemented and it worked for me.