# Test custom hook in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have this hook that should trigger `beforeunload` event when the compoenent is mounted and unmounted.

```ts
const UseHook = (fns: (e) => void) => {
  const cb = useRef(fns);

  useEffect(() => {
    cb.current = fn;
  }, [fn]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const onUnloadFN = (args: BeforeUnloadEvent) => cb.current?.(args);

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', onUnloadFN);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', onUnloadFN);
    };
  }, []);
};
```

Now I want to test the hook using jest and enzyme:

```ts
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';

const HookWrapper = () => {
  useHook((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = '';
  });

  return <div>component</div>;
};

describe('useHook', () => {
  const location: Location = window.location;
  delete window.location;
  const mockPageReloading = jest.fn();
  window.location = {
    ...location,
    reload: mockPageReloading,
  };
  it('should mount', () => {
    const mockedOnload = jest.fn();

    window.addEventListener = jest.fn((event) => {
      if (event === 'beforeunload') {
        mockedOnload();
      }
    });
    const wrapper = mount(<HookWrapper />);

    expect(mockedOnload).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
  });

  it('should unmount', () => {
    const mockedOnload = jest.fn();

    window.removeEventListener = jest.fn((event) => {
      if (event === 'beforeunload') {
        mockedOnload();
      }
    });
    const wrapper = mount(<HookWrapper />);
    wrapper.unmount();
    expect(mockedOnload).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

The first test pass, but the second retrieve that the event listener wasn't call on unmount (it was called 0 times).
Who can help with this?
Basically I want to test if the event was triggered on mount and also on unmount.
PS: this hook is also used to detect when user reload the page. If somebody has other idea how to test this hook, please let me know.

Comment: Shouldn't the function be called twice in the second test, both for mount and unmount?

Comment: You are right, how to test?

Comment: Could you show please? It will help me a lot

Comment: Huh? Change `expect(mockedOnload).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);` to `expect(mockedOnload).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);`...

Comment: Yes, but it is triggered 0 times according to the test result

Comment: I would suggest wrapping the code you currently have under `describe`, before the first `it`, inside a `beforeEach(() => { ... })` call. You may want to add the `jest.restoreAllMocks()` to that `beforeEach` call also (but I haven't used mocks in jest, so if that doesn't work, try removing it everywhere :)).

Comment: Could you please show how the code should look? To understand better the idea. And if it will work I will accept the answer. It will be very helpful

Comment: I have a paying job I need to attend to. If you can't follow the directions given, wait until someone with more expertise in jest and react testing chimes in.

Comment: It works fine for me after I changed the `fns` -> `fn`

Comment: That was a type error , I will change the code, the second test pass on your side?

Comment: @slideshowp2, may you help with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69333783/test-react-dropdown-using-enzyme

Comment: @HereticMonkey, could you help please with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69428679/send-a-request-inside-a-rendered-list-of-elements-in-reactjs