# Test react dropdown using enzyme

Tags: reactjs

I am using React js and `Autocomplete` component from `@mui/material/Autocomplete`. Here you can see how it works. https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-night-7id9z?file=/index.js .
 I want to test this component using enzyme. My test looks like this:

```js
import {mount} from "enzyme";
import AutocompleteComponent from "./Autocomplete";

describe('autocomplete', () => {
    test('should trigger on change', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(<AutocompleteComponent/>);
        const input = wrapper.find('input');

        input.simulate('change', 'John');
        expect(input.props('value')).toContain('John')
        console.log(input.debug())
    })
})
```

My component code looks like this:

```js
const WithMaterialUI = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      freeSolo
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      name="test"
      options={["2", "3"]}
      onInputChange={(_, val) => {
        setData(val);
      }}
      onChange={(_, val) => {
        setData(val);
      }}
      value={data}
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField name="test" {...params} label="Movie" />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

Running this test i got:
`Expected value:  "John" Received object: {"aria-activedescendant": null, "aria-autocomplete": "list", "aria-controls": null, "aria-describedby": undefined, "aria-invalid": false, "autoCapitalize": "none", "autoComplete": "off", "autoFocus": false, "className": "MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input MuiAutocomplete-input MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd", "defaultValue": undefined, "disabled": false, "id": "combo-box-demo", "name": "test", "onAnimationStart": [Function handleAutoFill], "onBlur": [Function handleBlur], "onChange": [Function handleChange], "onFocus": [Function handleFocus], "onKeyDown": undefined, "onKeyUp": undefined, "onMouseDown": [Function handleInputMouseDown], "placeholder": undefined, "readOnly": undefined, "required": false, "rows": undefined, "spellCheck": "false", "type": "text", "value": "test"}`.
 How to test if the value is changed in the input and why my test failed?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is how you need to simulate the change event:

```
input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Hello' } })
```

My source is:
https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/76#issuecomment-189606849

Comment: could you help with one more thing. I changed a lit a bit my code and now the dropdown will open only if user type more than 1 letter. Could you know how to test this behaviour?

Comment: Sure, you need to mock the onChange method of the component, simulate a change with one letter value like 'a' and make sure it is not been called, and then simulate a change with value like 'aa' and make it has been called

Comment: can you open the demo from codesanbox, because i think you did not understand what i want to test. So basically, when user type more than one letter he should open the dropdown, the dropdown should not be opened if in the input are less than 1 symbol. Could you help?

Comment: could you help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69820669/test-the-changed-state-after-useeffect-has-runned