# Test the changed state after useEffect has runned

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use ReactJs, jest and react testing library. I have this code:

```js
const App = ({data}) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(); // after useEffect runs state should be false
  console.log('test state', state)
  useEffect(() => {
     setState(!data) 
  }, [])
  return <p>'data is' {data},<p/>
}

<App data={12}  />
```

After the useEffect will run the state should be `false`. Now i want to test the component using jest and react testing library.

```js
describe('App', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    const setValue = jest.fn(x => {});
    React.useState = jest.fn()
      .mockImplementationOnce(x => [x, setValue])
  })
  test('It should render the correct value', async() => {
      const v = utils.queryByText(12)
      expect(v).toBeInTheDocument()
    })
  })
})
```

When i run the test  in `console.log('test state', state)` i get for first time `console.log('test state', undefined)` and after that `console.log('test state', false)`, but i need to get only the `false` value, because due the fact that for the first time the value is `undefined` the test fails. How to do this?

Comment: Set initial value true `const [state, setState] = useState(true);`

Comment: @Asifvora, if i set that, on the first render i get `true` and on the second `false`, but i need to use only `false`, so to wait after useEffect will run.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wait until the component did mount and then run your expectation. In react testing library, there is a special method for it. `waitFor`.

from React testing library [documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor):

> When in need to wait for any period of time you can use waitFor, to wait for your expectations to pass.

```
import {waitFor} from '@testing-library/react'

describe('App', () => {
  // rest of the codes ...
  test('It should render the correct value', async() => {
      const v = utils.queryByText(12)

      await waitFor(() => {
         expect(v).toBeInTheDocument()
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting two console logs because this line initialises your state (`undefined`):

```
const [state, setState] = useState();
```

After that the `useEffect` hook runs `onComponentDidMount` and changes the state, which causes the component to rerender (second log statement).

You could use something like this, if you want to init the state from the `props`:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(!data);
```

Update:

This works on my machine:
[image: source file]

[image: test file]

[image: result]

Maybe you have some typos?

[image]

Comment: i need to use useEffect because i need the value only on first render, so i can't use it directly in useState.

Comment: is there a posibility to run the test after the useEffect will run?

Comment: I'm having difficulties to understand your question. So the problem is that the test case is failing? Maybe use `.mockImplementation` instead of `.mockImplementationOnce`?

Comment: the isse is next: when i run the test for the first time i get `undefined` in console.log and on the second render i get the expected value `false`, but doe the fact that the first render is not the expected one, the test fails. Question is, how to run the test only after the useEffect  runned?

Comment: maybe something like that?

``` 
expect(setValue).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
expect(setValue).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(false);
```

Comment: i need to test the returned value, not the state. Could you help?

Comment: Could you please update the code snippets in the question or post a link to the Github repo?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238822/discussion-between-asking-and-michael-haar).

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode