# Mock Router in React testing library and jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library, babel-jest

I'm writing unit test with React testing library and Jest and wants to check if my React Component is successfully able to navigate to next Page.

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import appStore from '../../src/app/redux/store';
import { MemoryRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { Router } from 'react-router';

const setup = (initialEntries = []) => {
      let inMemHistory = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries });
      const utils = render(
        <Router history={inMemHistory}>
          <Provider store={appStore}>
            <Component-1 />
          
          </Provider>
        </Router>
      );
 
      const saveButtonElem = screen.getByRole('button', { name: "Save and Continue" });
      return {
            saveButtonElem,
            inMemHistory,
            ...utils,
      }
};
```

Test:

```
test('should be able to navigate', async () => {
            const {
                 saveButtonElem,
                  inMemHistory,
                  getByText,
                  queryByText,
                  queryAllByText,
            } = setup(["/component_add"]);

        // Content of Test

            // Saving Config
            fireEvent.click(saveButtonElem);
            console.info("Current Path", inMemHistory.location.pathname);
// Got /component_add on console
// Expected /component_data  after clicking on save button
   
      })
```

I've tried waiting for 5 second after clicking save button and then tried to print path, but results are same.

Comment: Are you using React Router (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/65270992/3001761) or similar? _How_ does your component navigate? Give a [mre].

Comment: People who try to help usually need more explicit details. I have answered based on my understanding of your question. Hope it helps.

Comment: I've edited the question and added more details to it, see you need more details, I've implemented Option-2 suggested by @KarthikR

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you use react-router, You can use the Memory router for the testing which is easier and performant. I might have typos or syntax errors as I type without IDE support. But it should help you with idea on what I propose.

**Option 1:**

```
it("should route to the expected page", () => {
  let mockHistory, mockLocation;
  render(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/currentUri"]}>
      <Component1 />
      // Dummy route that routes for all urls
      <Route
        path="*"
        render={({ history, location }) => {
          mockHistory= history;
          mockLocation= location;
          return null;
        }}
      />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
  // navigate here on event
  userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: /Save/}));
  expect(mockLocation.pathname).toBe("/expectedUri");
});
```

**Option 2:**

```
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { Router } from 'react-router';

const renderWithHistory = (initialEntries= [], Component) => {
  let inMemHistory = createMemoryHistory({
    initialEntries
  });
  return { 
      ...render(
        <Router history={inMemHistory}>
          <Component />
        </Router >
      ), history };
};

it("should route to the expected page", () => {
      const { history } = renderWithHistory(['/currentUri'], Component1);
      // navigate here on event
      userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: /Save/}));
      expect(history.location.pathname).toBe("/expectedUri");
});
```

Comment: how will it come to know where does it need to navigate, is it smart enough to do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean..your code does that right? On click of save? Your test case was just supposed to verify the updated URL

Comment: on save button click, I'm getting same path as I'm passing in intialEntries