# Jest.js: Mocking URLSearchParams return value to null fails to push test into falsey test path

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

```
jest.spyOn( URLSearchParams.prototype, 'get' ).mockReturnValue( null )
```

I am expecting this code to cause `get` to evaluate to `null` but this doesn't appear to be the case, `Istanbul` is being used and the code below does not ever evaluate to the falsey condition (shown as a failure to cover `?? ''`:

```
    const startDate: string = new URLSearchParams( queryParams ).get( 'start' ) ?? ''
    const endDate: string = new URLSearchParams( queryParams ).get( 'end' ) ?? ''
```

Any idea what the issue might be?

For context here is the start of the relevant component and test:

```
// component under test:
const EmployeeTable = () => {
    const queryParams = useLocation().search
    const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>()
    const employeeId: number = Number( id )
    const startDate: string = new URLSearchParams( queryParams ).get( 'start' ) ?? ''
    const endDate: string = new URLSearchParams( queryParams ).get( 'end' ) ?? ''

// the jest test
    it( 'should render the employee table page section without data', () => {
        jest.spyOn( dataHooks, 'useEmployeeTimeSummaries' ).mockImplementation( (): any => ( {
            data: null,
        } ) )
        jest.spyOn( URLSearchParams.prototype, 'get' ).mockReturnValue( null )
        const { getByTestId } = render( <EmployeeTable />, { wrapper: reactQueryProvider } )
        expect( getByTestId( TEST_ID_EMPLOYEE_TABLE ) ).toBeInTheDocument()
    } )
```

Comment: Why mock `URLSearchParams` at all? It's much easier, and far less coupled to the details of your implementation, to control the location: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/testing, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65275037/3001761