# How to override default mock of useParams in jest

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, jestjs, mocking

I have to test a component which renders based on the country and language in the url path params. So I want to the if the components are rendered properly based on the change in params.

I am mocking the useParams and setting some required value which works for most of the tests. Now for a specific case, I need to change the param.

```
   jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
      ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
      useParams: () => ({
        language: 'IT'
      })
    }));
```

How do I override the language in test ?

Thank you

Comment: Don't mock what you don't own, try something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/65275037/3001761.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of mocking `useParams` you can use [`<MemoryRouter initialEntries>`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#memoryrouter), for example:

*`MyComponent.js`*

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function MyComponent() {
  const { language } = useParams();
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>My Component page</h2>
      <p>language: {language}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

*`MyComponent.test.js`*

```
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import App from "./App";

test("Home: Go to `MyComponent: en`", async () => {
  render(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/"]}>
      <App />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  expect(screen.getByText("Home page")).toBeInTheDocument();

  fireEvent.click(screen.getByText("My Component: en"));

  expect(screen.getByText("language: en")).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(screen.queryByText("language: fr")).not.toBeInTheDocument();
});

test("MyComponent: en", async () => {
  render(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/myComponent/en"]}>
      <App />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  expect(screen.getByText("language: en")).toBeInTheDocument();
});

test("MyComponent: fr", async () => {
  render(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/myComponent/fr"]}>
      <App />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  expect(screen.getByText("language: fr")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Online demo

[image: Edit eloquent-tu-imqcbh]

Comment: This is a nice solution, I need to try this out (in the meantime I found a solution/hack) and if it works, i'll accept this answer

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this works? The first test seems like it shouldn't pass, the language is never set to "en" and your component doesn't default to anything so it should never render to show "language: en" like your expect statement says.

Comment: @Duskendale Have you seen the codesandbox example ? The first test starts from the home page, then a click is made on the link with the text `My Component: en` that redirects to `/myComponent/en`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [page](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter) on the Jest docs, try the following

```js
// create a separate mock function that you can access from tests
// NOTE: the name must start with `mock` and is case sensitive 
const mockUseParams = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
  language: 'IT',
});

// mock the module using the mock function created above
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useParams: () => mockUseParams(),
}));

it('should behave differently when the params change', () => {
  mockUseParams.mockReturnValueOnce({
    language: 'EN',
  });

  // test implementation
});
```

Comment: Tried but i got `ReferenceError: mockUseParams is not defined` at the "mock initialization"

Comment: yeah can't get this to work either

Comment: It was so promising (looks like exactly what I needed), but it didn't work as well - the return of the mocked `useParams()` was undefined.

Answer (score 0):

yes
Include the Router in your App component;
Always render the App component in your tests (never child components like Locations);
Navigate to your pages in tests by finding and clicking links on the page
The positives of this approach: you don’t need to read the rest of this post  (and your test setup will be less complicated). The negatives: you can’t immediately load a routing history (the current page and previous pages) in test setup; you need to go through all the user interactions to build the history.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this :

```
const mockUseParams = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
    slug: 'param1',
    id: '123',
});

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
    useParams: () => mockUseParams(),
}));
```

And to update the params :

```
mockUseParams.mockReturnValueOnce({
  slug: 'param2',
  id: '123',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution worked well for me

```
let mockUseParams = {
  language: 'IT',
};

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useParams: () => mockUseParams,
}));

it('test with different param', () => {
    mockUseParams.language: 'EN'
  // test implementation
});
```