# Can we mock a jest mock and use it every file?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router, react-router-dom, enzyme

I've defined a jest mock which mocks 'react-router-dom'. In my React Component Test, I'm using that mock to see if that has been called with "/". This is how I've mocked it:

```
const mockedUsedNavigate = jest.fn()
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useNavigate: () => mockedUsedNavigate,
}))
```

I want to use the same mock in other component test files, is there a way I could do this?
I tried creating `__mocks___` directory and mocked it like this:

```
export const navigationMock = {
  useNavigate: jest.fn(),
}
```

But test failed when calling `expect(navigationMock.useNavigate).toHaveBeenCalled()` fails

Comment: Don't do that at all. Don't mock what you don't own, and don't partially mock things. Do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65275037/3001761.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mock `useNavigate` hook, incorrect mock may break the implementation. That's the one reason like @jonrsharpe said:

> Don't mock what you don't own

Instead, you should use the [MemoryRouter](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#memoryrouter) component for testing.

> A `<MemoryRouter>` stores its locations internally in an array. Unlike `<BrowserHistory>` and `<HashHistory>`, it isn't tied to an external source, like the history stack in a browser. This makes it ideal for scenarios where you need complete control over the history stack, like testing.

E.g.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import * as TestRenderer from "react-test-renderer";
import {
  MemoryRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  useNavigate
} from "react-router";

describe("useNavigate", () => {
  it("transitions to the new location", () => {
    function Home() {
      let navigate = useNavigate();

      function handleClick() {
        navigate("/about");
      }

      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Home</h1>
          <button onClick={handleClick}>click me</button>
        </div>
      );
    }

    let renderer: TestRenderer.ReactTestRenderer;
    TestRenderer.act(() => {
      renderer = TestRenderer.create(
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/home"]}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="about" element={<h1>About</h1>} />
          </Routes>
        </MemoryRouter>
      );
    });

    let button = renderer.root.findByType("button");

    TestRenderer.act(() => {
      button.props.onClick();
    });

    expect(renderer.toJSON()).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
      <h1>
        About
      </h1>
    `);
  });
```