# Jest: Test useNavigate hook in function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-router-dom

I'm writing test with Jest and want to test a simple button that serves as logout and redirect you to `"/login"` via `onClick`.

```
import {loginService} from "../../utils/loginService";
import React from "react";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";

const Logout = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const logout = e => {
        loginService.logout();
        navigate("/login");
    }

    return (
        <button className={'logout'} onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
    )
}

export default Logout
```

I was able to write a first test that renders the button and checks if it is there. A second test should check, that on click the browser redirects you to "/login".

```
import Logout from "../../components/navbar/Logout";
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import {fireEvent, render} from "@testing-library/react";
import {screen} from '@testing-library/react';

describe('Test Logout Button', () => {
    it('it is rendered', () => {
        render(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Logout/>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
        expect(screen.getByText(/logout/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
    })

    it('it redirects after click', () => {
        const mockedUsedNavigate = jest.fn();

        jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
            ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
            useNavigate: () => mockedUsedNavigate,
        }));

        render(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Logout/>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
        const logout = screen.getByText(/logout/i);

        fireEvent.click(logout);

        // TODO something something check useNavigate
        // https://blog.logrocket.com/testing-react-router-usenavigate-hook-react-testing-library/
        expect(mockedUsedNavigate).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    })
})
```

This however fails:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0
```

I would assume that I would somehow have to pass the mock to my component. How would I do that or do I even have to do that? How do I check that `useNavigate` has redirected to `"/login"`? As far as I'm concerned `<BrowserRouter />` does not have a history attribute.

Comment: Don't mock what you don't own, and don't partially mock things. The answer below fixes the timing problem, but doesn't actually lead to high quality tests. The approach I illustrate here is far better practice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65275037/3001761.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jest.mock` should be done outside of your unit tests as it needs to mock out a dependency before it is evaluated by the code you want to test. In your example, `react-router-dom` library is first evaluated by the `Logout` component and then your code attempts to mock it out which is too late. So you should move the following code outside of the `describe`:

```
const mockedUsedNavigate = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
    useNavigate: () => mockedUsedNavigate,
}));
```

Of course, all of your tests would then be using the same instance of `mockedUsedNavigate` which can be error prone, so you should reset it before each unit test by adding it to a beforeEach as follows:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  mockedUsedNavigate.mockReset();
});
```