# React testing library-ReferenceError: Cannot access '' before initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am mocking useNavigate to test my login page redirect works after login. But I got this reference error.

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mockedUsedNavigate' before initialization

      12 | jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
      13 |   ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
    > 14 |   useNavigate: () => mockedUsedNavigate,
```

I've looked through the forum and aware it might be the `jest.mock()` hoisted to the top but I did define `mockedUsedNavigate` before the mock.

```
// mock useNavigate
const mockedUsedNavigate = jest.fn()

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useNavigate: () => mockedUsedNavigate, 
}))
```

code for my login page:

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (isSignup) {
      dispatch(signup(formData, navigate))
    } else {
      dispatch(signin(formData, navigate))
    }
  }
```

However, the same test code works for my other project.

Comment: Can you share the code that shows how the ```mockedUsedNavigate``` variable is used?

Comment: _Don't_ mock useNavigate (in general, don't mock what you don't own); test the behaviour not the implementation. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65275037/3001761.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried what you suggested and it works if I put `navigate('/')` after the dispatch in the same component. However, the original idea was passing `navigate` in my login dispatch actions and excute `navigate('/')` after getting server response. How do you handle situation like this, where `navigate('/')` is not in the rendered component? Hope I'm explained well..

Comment: @OvidijusParsiunas I used this line  `await waitFor(() => expect(mockedUsedNavigate).toHaveBeenCalled())`