# Mocked useNavigate is not working, expected number of calls: >= 1, received number of calls: 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

I have a Login.js inside which I have imported useNavigate from react-router-dom. I called a useNavigate hook at the top level of the functional component like that:
`const navigate = useNavigate();`

and I use that later like that:
`<div onClick={() => navigate("/register")}>Create</div>`

I was trying to test this code with jest and react-testing-library, it works fine without a mock but when i try it with mocked useNavigate like that:

```
test('test navigate to register', () => { 
    const mockedUsedNavigate = jest.fn();
    jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
        ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
        useNavigate: () => mockedUsedNavigate
      }));

      render(
       <Router>
         <Login />
       </Router>,
       );

    const registerButton = screen.getByText(/Create/i);
    fireEvent.click(registerButton);
    expect(mockedUsedNavigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

the test is failing.

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
```

What could be the problem?

Update - my goal is to have 2 unit tests. One for checking whether the function that is called after clicking on a specific div is working properly, (that's just working fine, the test is passing). The other test is to check that after clicking on that specific div a proper function with a proper param will be called. The reason I want to use mock is that I don't want to make any real changes, just to check the call. I do know that the first test already verifies that the proper function was called with the right param, but I kind of want to have as little units tested as possible, so if something breaks it will be clear what went wrong.

Comment: `expect(mockedUsedNavigate).toHaveBeenCalled()` creating a new `jest.fn` isn't what you want probably

Comment: I would strongly recommend neither mocking what you don't own nor partially mocking things. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65270992/3001761 for tests that are behaviour- rather than implementation-based and therefore allow you do refactor confidently and keep your code maintainable.