# How to test onClick with Jest that is NOT a callback function in props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I found lots of ways of using mock functions in jest to spy on callback functions that are passed down to a component but nothing on testing a simple `onClick` that is defined in the same component.

My Example Page:

```
const ExamplePage: NextPage = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const onClick = (): Promise<void> => {
        axios.post(`/api/track`, {
            eventName: Event.TRACK_CLICK,
        });
        router.push("/new-route");
        return Promise.resolve();
    };

    return (
        <Container data-testid="container">
            <Title>Example Title</Title>
            <CreateButton data-testid="create-button" onClick={onClick}>
                Create Partner
            </CreateButton>
        </Container>
    );
};

export default ExamplePage;
```

My current test where I am attempting to get the `onClick` from `getAttribute`:

```
import { fireEvent, render } from "../../../../test/customRenderer";
import ExamplePage from "../../../pages/example-page";

describe("Example page", () => {
    it("has a button to create", () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<ExamplePage />);

        const createButton = getByTestId("create-button");

        expect(createButton).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    it(" the button's OnClick function should be executed when clicked", () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<ExamplePage />);
        // find the button
        const createButton = getByTestId("create-button");
        // check the button has onClick
        expect(createButton).toHaveAttribute("onClick");
        // get the onClick function
        const onClick = createButton.getAttribute("onClick");
        fireEvent.click(createButton);
        // check if the button's onClick function has been executed
        expect(onClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

The above fails since there is no `onClick` attribute only `null`. My comments in the test highlight my thought process of trying to reach down into this component for the function on the button and checking if it has been called.

**Is there any way to test a `onClick` that is self contained in a react component?**

Comment: Probably no way.

Comment: Of course there is, you just test the _behaviour_ instead of the implementation. Use a test double for the request, test the navigation by where you end up (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65275037/3001761).

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide mocked router provider and expect that a certain route is pushed to the routers. You also need extract the RestAPI into a separate module and mock it! You can use Dependency Injection, IOC container or import the Api in the component and mock it using jest. I will leave the RestAPi mocking to you.

Mocking router details here: [How to mock useRouter](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7479)

```js
  const useRouter = jest.spyOn(require('next/router'), 'useRouter')


  describe("", () => {
    it("",() => {
       const pushMock = jest.fn();
      
       // Mocking Rest api call depends on how you are going to "inject it" in the component
       const restApiMock = jest.jn().mockResolvedValue();

       useRouter.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
         push: pushMock,
       }))
       const rendrResult = render(<ExamplePage />);
       
       //get and click the create button

     //expect the "side" effects of clicking the button

      expect(restApiMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(pushMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/new-route");
    });
  });
```